# HTML skip a line not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know there are many ways to skip a line in html such as `<p></p>` or `<br>` or even `&nbsp;` but none of these seem to be working on this part of my webpage.

Here you can see that the "$1" is stuck next to the "select number of wins" slider. I want it to be below it, thats why I need to skip a line.
Picture: https://gyazo.com/4bb88135162f40d3d729a086b1b2e3ff
Webpage: https://www.counterboosting.com/buy-csgo-rank-boosting/

This is the HTML of that part of the page

```
<div class="col-md-6 wins wow fadeInLeft" style="padding-top:80px">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4">
        <strong>Select number of wins</strong>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-4" id="jqslider"></div><br>
    <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-5">
        <br>
        <br>
        <center>
            <input id="amount" max="5" min="1" size="10" type="text" value=
            "1"> <input id="amountf" name="win_num" type="hidden" value="">
        </center>
    </div><input name="date" type="hidden" value=
    "2016-07-19 15.37"><input class="" id="pricefw" name="cost" type=
    "hidden" value="">
    <p class="text-center" id="price">Price - €</p>
    <p class="text-center"><button class=
    "btn btn-system btn-large center-block" name="submit" type=
    "submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Pay
    with Paypal/G2A PAY</button></p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for some fix or a reasoning behind this! :)

Comment: Probably you should close the hidden input tag and place the <p> tag with the price in another div

Comment: Hey OP - you know that you can insert images in to the post?

Comment: I would suggest setting up a jsfiddle/codepen to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: The webpage contains a lot of errors; 58 according to the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.counterboosting.com%2Fbuy-csgo-rank-boosting%2F). If you correct all of them, does the problem persist?

Comment: by the way `&nbsp;` does not make a new line on it's own, it inserts a space.

Comment: @DanielHarrin under the right circumstances, nbsp can simulate a new line, e.g. when you put it in between two paragraphs (it will break the margin collapsing). Not sure the OP meant that though.

Comment: @MrLister yeah i suppose so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.price{     
   float: left;
   margin-left: -130px;
   margin-top: -15px;
}
```

You can move price next line by using above CSS but this is not a good way to fix the issue.

Use another `div` to move next line. Because your `.grid [class*="col-"]` have `display: inline block`.